# apply custom filter to entire windows desktop (final render step?)

Tags: c#, winapi

What classes/methods/variables in the windows api would provide the hooks necessary to alter the appearance of the windows desktop.  I am mainly interested in Windows 7.  Links to appropriate msdn pages of relevant classes/methods etc. would be great.

Specifically: I want to modify the colors of anything rendered to the desktop with a custom 4D (RGBA) interpolation table.  Hoping there is a hook in the desktop rendering pipeline where I can just insert a custom method.

I'm not too worried about performance -- if it performed as well as a remote desktop connection, that'd be great.

Suggestions of a better approach would also be welcome.  Not looking for complete solution -- just pointers to the relevant parts of the windows api.

Comment: I don't know how things like [the old "Windows 95" screensaver](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Coaq7g7fs58#t=554) and accessibility programs did it (in the latter case, with an "Invert Screen Colors" option), but try there?

Comment: I had looking for that for months without success. Have a look at *mirror driver*.